# Issue with sending an image at a specific collection view index to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I know this might seem as a question asked many times by other users. I did go through many of them but I am not able to figure out the exact reason for my issue.

I am showing a set of images on the collection view from a url and they are stored in an array of type `UIImage`. Now when I click on the collection view, the image at that particular index should be shown in another `viewcontroller`.

In `didSelectItemAt` I am doing this...

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         self.thumbnailImage.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row]
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "catalogueDetailIdentifier", sender: nil)

}
```

But at this line I am getting a crash saying it unexpectedly found nil. Because of this I am not able to go forward.

Also in the `prepareForSegue`, I have done this...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "myIdentifier" {

        if let targetVC = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController {
            targetVC.myImage = photoThumbnail.image

        }
    }
}
```

But the crash itself has to be resolved first. Any help will be appreciated...:)

Comment: Your problem seems really easy to solve. But you need to provide a little more code. How do you put the images in the array?

Comment: @Jonas Schafft  this is how I added the images...
self.arrayOfURLImages.append(self.sampleImageView.image!)

Comment: Please do: print(indexPath.row) and print(self.arrayOfURLImages.count) and tell me what it prints

Comment: the count of images is 5 and the indexpath.row is also shown properly starting from 0

Comment: okay then your problem is the self.thumbnailImage. Where does this get initialized?

Comment: It is in didSelectItemAt.. that I am assigning the value to it for the 1st time. Also, its a variable of type UIImageView

Comment: Can you provide the full didSelectItemAt... function? I´m sure there is the problem. Just Edit your Question with the added function

Comment: @Jonas Schafft I have updated the didSelectItemAt...

Comment: I see. But your self.thumbnailImage is not initialized there. Its likely nil. Where do you create it? Something like self.thumbnailImage = UIImageView()  or a connection to the IB?

Comment: @D.M - you say you are adding images to an array with *" `self.arrayOfURLImages.append(self.sampleImageView.image!)` "* ... so you are (currently) creating an array of 5 of the same image... Is `self.sampleImageView.image` a valid UIImage?

Comment: Its created as a variable at the start itself like so...
var thumbnailImage: UIImageView!

Comment: :D there is the problem

Comment: @Jonas Schafft  will be glad to rectify it...:)

Comment: You need something like self.thumbnailImage = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)); Your self.thumbnailImage is not created. its just an empty variable from the type UIImageView

Comment: @Jonas Schafft you are saying this should also be added in didSelectRow.. along with what is already there..?

Comment: You could do this there. And you need to add it to your view as well. Because you want the image to appear somewhere right? self.view.addSubview(self.sampleImageView)

Comment: i posted the code as an answer. Just try it and look if the error disappears

Comment: @Jonas Schafft sure...

Comment: why you are not pass url to another controller ? just set image to imageview with lazy loading. and pass url to anotherVC and same task perform (lazy loading) in another VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

             self.thumbnailImage = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100));
             self.thumbnailImage.image = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row]
             performSegue(withIdentifier: "catalogueDetailIdentifier", sender: nil)

    }
```

But keep in mind that you also need to display the thumbnailImage with something like:

```
self.view.addSubview(self.sampleImageView)
```

**UPDATE: (Because i now understand that you just want to transfer it)**

```
var thumbnailImage: UIImage?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

         self.thumbnailImage = self.arrayOfURLImages[indexPath.row]
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "catalogueDetailIdentifier", sender: nil)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

  if segue.identifier == "catalogueDetailIdentifier" {

    if let targetVC = segue.destination as? DestinationViewController {
        targetVC.myImage = thumbnailImage!

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working now. Thanks a lot for the help...:)
Have given an upvote also..:)

Comment: Probably better to help D.M. do what he wants to do correctly, rather than this. It makes no sense to be instantiating a UIImageView here if all he wants to do is use it to "carry" a UIImage to another function.

Comment: I agree but it is really hard to explain everything here without seeing all of his code.

Comment: @DonMag you have another opinion?

Comment: ahh i see. i didnt even read his question properly. i update my answer with the right way. brb

Comment: @JonasSchafft you made any changes in the answer..? It doesn't seem so...

Comment: I updated my answer. Basically just don't use a UIImageView. A UIImage is enough

Comment: Cool!! @JonasSchafft  works perfect!! Thanks for the help. And may God bless you...:)

Comment: No problem. Glad i could help!